# gdal_array import error Red Hat linux

Tags: python, linux, importerror, gdal

I have gdal 2.2.4 installed and running python 3.5 on a Red Hat EL (7.3) cluster. I am able to import gdal and osgeo in python, but I get an import error that looks like this when I try to import gdal_array:

```
import gdal
import osgeo
import osr
from osgeo import gdal_array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py", line 28, in <module>
    _gdal_array = swig_import_helper()
  File "/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal_array', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/opt/anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/opt/anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal_array.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm
```

I installed gdal to my local user account using Anaconda (and have tried pip too). Some other info: gcc version is [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]. I'm not sure what's causing the error. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: You probably need to install the `numpy` package, see  https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/

Comment: numpy is installed. I don't believe that's it.

Comment: Did you installed the gdal binaries or did you compile them? This error could be related to an ABI issue between the libstdc++ used to compile gdal and the one that is present in your system, especially if it is an old version of Red Hat.

Comment: gdal was installed using Anaconda. I updated the original post with the Red Hat EL versions.

Comment: It is difficult for me to reproduce your issue, but this is what I learned so far: starting from GCC 5.1 a new ABI version was introduced that breaks the compatibility with older versions of libstdc++. It may be that the GDAL binaries that you are using use the new ABI, while your system libraries the old one. But this is just a supposition.  Possible solutions: use an older version of GDAL (e.g. 2.0) and see if this fixes your problem. Alternatively you can upgrade GCC (and the stdlibs) but this could break other applications that are running on your system.